# What's the best criteria for measuring how good candidates are for moderating?

Tags: discussion, support, election

The [2015 Community Moderator Election](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) began 3 days ago and ends in 5 days and I'm not confident who I am going to vote for or according what criteria  I'm going to vote. so, I thought I can ask Experienced users here to help me.

- candidate score : It is a brief description of users reputation and the badges they had earned.
- activities in meta : for instance the number of posts posted on meta or meta SE.
- reputation : somehow, Users with more than 10k reputation have moderation experience.
- some especial badges: for example *steward* and *marshal*
- experience:for example ex-moderators

Can these be a good factor to vote?

Comment: You could also look how the candidates react in comments or answer questions.

Comment: good idea, and [2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1) is also good for that.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had seen this already.

Comment: There is further information on candidates available on the [elections site](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#biology.stackexchange) too

Comment: About the 10k rep level: you should consider that the site recently graduated, and before that all users with 2000 rep had access to the moderation tools. Therefore, most of the candidates have quite a lot of experience with the current 10k tools.

Answer (score 2):

My votes were entirely based on the introductions and Q&A answers and the day-to-day moderating activities of each candidate and had nothing to do with the score. I think you should pick the candidates that reflect your ideas on what a moderator should do on stack exchange.

Comment: +1 - The only problem is that people sometimes aren't *completely* forthcoming (otherwise answers would be very, very long) on those questionnaires. One's decision should also include actions of that candidate (close voting, editing, comments, etc.) on the site. As they say, actions speak louder than words.

Comment: @anongoodnurse That's a good point that I hadn't thought to write here, but one which weighed on my decision.